# Setting AppPool Identity on Windows Server 2016 @ Azure Cloud Service throw COMException “directory property cannot be found in the cache.”

Tags: iis, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

**The following code** fail when executed on an Azure Guest OS Family 5 (Cloud Service webrole running Windows Server 2016):

```
using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    ApplicationPool applicationPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(name);
    applicationPool.AutoStart = true;
    applicationPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
    applicationPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";

    // START ISSUE:
    applicationPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
    applicationPool.ProcessModel.UserName = username;
    applicationPool.ProcessModel.Password = userPassword;
    applicationPool.ProcessModel["idleTimeoutAction"] = 1;
    // END ISSUE

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

**Exception:**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The directory property
>   cannot be found in the cache.

**More info**

The exception is thrown at CommitChanges, but only when we have the code setting AppPool identity (the 4 lines between START ISSUE and END ISSUE). So this issue happen when setting AppPool identity.

This code have been in production for some years, working fine on on-prem Windows Servers and Azure Guest OS Family 4. We run the code with elevated privileges (using `<Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>`) and from the command line with administrative privileges. Same exception, but only on WinSrv2016 Azure cloud.

**Workaround:**

If we regenerate the machine keys on the deployment as [described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2016/02/29/keyset-does-not-exist-exception-from-hresult-0x8009000d-while-changing-application-pool-identity-in-iis/), we stop experiencing this issue.

**Question:**

Is this an known issue on OS Family 5 Azure cloud service deployments that is being addressed? Any less obtrusive suggestions to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tested it on my side. When I set the App Pool Identity manually(Remote desktop to Web Role and reset the Identity using IIS Manager), I can reproduced the Keyset does not exist issue.

[image]

As described in the article which you post, the issue is caused by machine keys corrupt. I suggest you log this issue on cloud service feedback page.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role

Comment: Thanks @Amor - posted here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169386-cloud-services-web-and-worker-role/suggestions/20074726-machine-keys-corrupt-on-os-family-5-deployments